# RabbitMQ header exchange with list

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, rabbitmq-exchange

I am having some issues trying to understand how an exchange of type *headers* works.

Only one exchange, myExchange

Three queues:

1. myQueue1
2. myQueue2
3. myQueue3

Bindings:

1. myExchange => myQueue1 (x-match: any, myHeader: [test1])
2. myExchange => myQueue2 (x-match: any, myHeader: [test2])
3. myExchange => myQueue3 (x-match: any, myHeader: [test1, test2, test3])

I am expecting the header of the message to have multiple values; any combination of  *test1*, *test2*, *test3* (example: *test1* alone, *test1* and *test2*, *test3* and *test2*, etc...)

***myQueue3*** only receives messages if they have myHeaders:[*test1, test2, test3*]. I would expect ***myQueue3*** to get messages for, e.g. *test1* and *test2* as well.

***myQueue1*** only receives messages if they have myHeaders:[*test1*]. I would expect ***myQueue1*** to get messages for, e.g. *test1* and [*test1*, *test2*] as well.

Is there any way to achieve such behavior? Thank you

Comment: It looks like headers exchange binding doesn't work this way. AFAIR, they uses strict match, so if you have array value for some header, items position in that array matters. Maybe using regular topic exchange with (multiple) wildcard routing key binding will serve you better?

Comment: Using Routing Key will help in your case.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I have a trick.

Bindings:

- myExchange => myQueue1 (x-match: any, test1: true)
- myExchange => myQueue2 (x-match: any, test2: true)
- myExchange => myQueue3 (x-match: any, test1: true, test2: true, test3: true)

myQueue1 will receive all message with header containts {test1: true}.

myQueue2 will receive all message with header containts {test2: true}.

myQueue3 will receive all message with header containts one of this {test1: true}, {test2: true} or {test3: true}.

I prefer this, because Routing Key is limited by 255 bytes, but the limit of number of elements in header is very higth.

For performance, I don't know what it's the best.

Comment: Topic exchange is faster than headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare multiple bindings for the same queue.

In your case the queue 3 will have three different bindings.

[image: Multiple bindings]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments, I was trying to achieve something that at the moment is not supported. I will use routing keys.